# Other than querying information_schema.query_history any other way to know who create table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any way to force while creating a table, need to mention the Username mandatory to know the details from the table definition for the created object.

Comment: Not unless you add information to the table when you create it e.g. in the comment or in a tag

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could give every use a different default role, then the `TABLE_OWNER` column of the table in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` would reflect the default role the user used/had when creating the table.

Disclaimer. I do not know if this is a **good idea**.  It might depend on how many users you have.

It is also not totally robust as a user could always `GRANT OWNERSHIP` of a table to another role to "hide" the fact that they created a given table. You could revoke `MANAGE GRANTS` privileges from such users to ensure that

> a role that does not have the MANAGE GRANTS privilege can only transfer ownership from itself to a child role within the role hierarchy.

but that might be too restrictive within the context of your security model.